# Nuxt.js changes formatting on json data in data attribute depending on nesting

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have following simple vue component with the attribute **data-hs-go-to-options** containing json data.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <a
      class="js-go-to go-to position-fixed"
      href="javascript:;"
      style="visibility: hidden"
      data-hs-go-to-options='{
          "offsetTop": 700,
          "position": {
          "init": {
              "right": 50
          },
          "show": {
              "bottom": 15      
          },
          "hide": {
              "bottom": -15
          }
          }
          }'
        >
      <i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i>
    </a> 
  </div>
</template>
```

When I build the nuxt app and try to fetch the data attribute with following command

`$('.js-go-to').attr('data-hs-go-to-options')`

I receive this:

```
"{
        "
```

When I remove the div element from the template above, build and run the command again, I get the correct content:

```
"{
      "offsetTop": 700,
      "position": {
      "init": {
          "right": 50
      },
      "show": {
          "bottom": 15      
      },
      "hide": {
          "bottom": -15
      }
      }
      }"
```

The rendered site content with the div looks like this:

```
<div><a href="javascript:;" data-hs-unfold-options="{
                    "target": "#footerLanguage",
                    "type": "css-animation",
                    "animationIn": "slideInDown"
                    }" class="js-hs-unfold-invoker dropdown-toggle btn btn-xs btn-soft-secondary"></a></div>
```

without the div like this:

```
<a href="javascript:;" data-hs-unfold-options="{
                  &quot;target&quot;: &quot;#footerLanguage&quot;,
                  &quot;type&quot;: &quot;css-animation&quot;,
                  &quot;animationIn&quot;: &quot;slideInDown&quot;
                  }" class="js-hs-unfold-invoker dropdown-toggle btn btn-xs btn-soft-secondary"></a>
```

I have no idea why this happens, can somebody please help?

Comment: I don't have a specific answer to nuxt.js, but for this exact reason I would highly recommend url-encoding your json *before* inserting it into the html. I would be highly willing to bet that if you use an encoded string so that it's valid html either way, you will have a much more consistent result, and it's as simple as parsing the url encoded string before parsing it as json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Vue** treats your JSON as a `string` in this case.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <a
      class="js-go-to go-to position-fixed"
      href="javascript:;"
      style="visibility: hidden"
      data-hs-go-to-options='{
          "offsetTop": 700,
          "position": {
          "init": {
              "right": 50
          },
          "show": {
              "bottom": 15      
          },
          "hide": {
              "bottom": -15
          }
          }
          }'
        >
      <i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i>
    </a> 
  </div>
</template>
```

Bind the data to the element by putting a `:` before the directive, so you tell **Nuxt** that it should be an `object`, not a `string`:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <a
      class="js-go-to go-to position-fixed"
      href="javascript:;"
      style="visibility: hidden"
      :data-hs-go-to-options='{
        "offsetTop": 700,
        "position": {
          "init": {
            "right": 50
          },
          "show": {
            "bottom": 15      
          },
          "hide": {
            "bottom": -15
          }
        }
      }'
    >
      <i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i>
    </a> 
  </div>
</template>
```

If you use it in **jQuery** then use `JSON.stringify()` first, so everything is escaped as necessary:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <a
      class="js-go-to go-to position-fixed"
      href="javascript:;"
      style="visibility: hidden"
      :data-hs-go-to-options='JSON.stringify({
        "offsetTop": 700,
        "position": {
          "init": {
            "right": 50
          },
          "show": {
            "bottom": 15      
          },
          "hide": {
            "bottom": -15
          }
        }
      })'
    >
      <i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i>
    </a> 
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: The ':' before the directive with JSON.stringify worked. Thanks so much! 
Although I'm still confused why it's treated sometimes as string and sometimes not.

Comment: @titech it's always treated as `string`, *UNLESS* you do the binding (`v-bind:something` or simply `:something`). The difference is that in some cases a `string` works, in some cases some other **JS** format is needed (like `Object`, `Array`, etc). So, it's not enough to wrap curly braces (`{ }`) around something - even the braces are going to be `strings` if you don't tell, that it should be evaluated as JS :)